# Using JasperReports without iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I would like to use JasperReports as a reporting library, but I can't use iReport (as I have learned from some sites), because the connection to the database and my requests are done from Java (I have done some complex calculations).

I have seen a lot of example that use iReport but I haven't seen one without it.

Also my reports should contain a lot of charts, it is painful to write all of that manually because I will generate a lot of reports and charts!!

My questions:

1. Is there an example how to do that? (I am using Java and JSF.)
2. Is a possible to use iReport? :)

Answer (score 0):

*Mmmh, I just noticed this question was asked more then 6 years ago... Will leave my answer here as reference.*

If I understand correctly you want to create Jaspersoft reports without using Ireport or Jaspersoft Studio. As the report templates are in essence XML this is possible. For more information on the structure... see amongst other : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/index.htm

To compile the report from it's source to the compiled report you can use IReport or Jaspersoft Studio. This can however also be done from Java code as shown here: https://www.developer.com/java/getting-started-with-jasperreport.html This reference is based on a quick search on the internet.

Hope this helps.

Kind regards.